# How to resolve "Count = error CS0103: The name 'InnerExceptionCount' does not exist in the current context" from too many API requests

Tags: c#, angularjs, api, asp.net-core

I get this error whenever my Angular code executes the API get requests too many times within a few seconds and then I quickly change views.

In my view page I have a "Call API" button to refresh the results by calling the API. If I quickly hit the button once or twice and then change the view I get this error. However if I hit the button quickly a few times then wait about 10 seconds then change the view, it doesn't happen. The more times I hit the "Call API" button, the more times the "AggregateException" error pops up.

my code looks like this;

```
    [HttpGet("Bookings-All")]
    public JsonResult AllBookings()
    {
        AppUser user = _userManagerService.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User).Result;

        IEnumerable<Booking> Bookings = _repoBooking.GetAll().OrderByDescending(d => d.BookingDateTime).ToList();
        return Json(listErrorMsg(AllBookings.Select(a => new
        {
            bookingId = a.BookingId,
            bookingDateTime = $"{a.BookingDateTime.ToString("HH:mm")} - {a.BookingDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")} | {a.BookingDateTime.DayOfWeek}",
            projectId = a.ProjectId,
            toFix = a.ToFix,
            toOrder = a.ToOrder,
            toSpray = a.ToSpray,
            jobType = a.JobType,
            bookingStatus = a.BookingStatus,
            clientId = a.ClientId == null ? "" : a.ClientId,
            clientName = a.ClientId == null ? "" : $"{_userManagerService.FindByIdAsync(a.ClientId).Result.FirstName} {_userManagerService.FindByIdAsync(a.ClientId).Result.LastName}",

            clientPhone = a.ClientId == null ? "" : $"{_userManagerService.FindByIdAsync(a.ClientId).Result.PhoneNumber}",

            projectAddress = a.ProjectId.ToString() == null ? ""
            : $"{_repoProject.GetSingle(p => p.ProjectId == a.ProjectId).streetNumber} {_repoProject.GetSingle(p => p.ProjectId == a.ProjectId).streetName}"
        })));
    }
```

How should I go about fixing this? Would putting a limit on the amount of requests approx. every 5 seconds help? This is happening in my dev environment but also on my Azure hosted web app with a free subscription. Would this problem solve itself once I upgrade my account?

I'll be putting a "cooldown" period between requests in my frontend with JS but also looking for a backend solution to prevent circumventing the front end code, I also suspect I may have problems with many users on the App at the same time. I appreciate any input, thanks.

Comment: Any stacktrace you can share? If this is a .NET Core app the misleading error message could be caused by this: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1006. I presume there's something going wrong in one of the async methods you are calling.